# How do I create transaction instructions?

Tags: transactions, instructions, solana-py

I’m learning how to send transactions through solana-py. I have everything down except for instructions. How do I calculate them?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do? In particular, what are you trying to calculate? In general you'd add instructions by calling the `add` function on a `Transaction` object: https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/transaction/#solana.transaction.Transaction.add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like they've got classes for creating certain instruction types, such as `transfer`:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.system_program import TransferParams, transfer
from solana.transaction import Transaction

client = Client("http://localhost:8899", "confirmed")
txn = Transaction().add(
    transfer(
        TransferParams(
            from_pubkey=sender.public_key, 
            to_pubkey=receiver.public_key, 
            lamports=10000000
        )
    )
)
client.send_transaction(txn, sender)
```

Or they also allow you to create the raw instructions:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solana.transaction import Transaction, TransactionInstruction

txn = Transaction().add(
    TransactionInstruction(
        keys=[sender.public_key, receiver.public_key],
        program_id="some-program-id",
        data=bytes("Hello")
    )
)
client.send_transaction(txn, sender)
```

The documentation is a little tough to navigate but you can find it [here](https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/core/transaction/#solana.transaction.TransactionInstruction)